# What is the proper modern C++ way to allow access to a member std::vector?

Tags: c++

I have a class which has an array of pointer objects and I'm converting it to a `std::vector` implementation.  I'm new to "modern" c++.

Currently the class exposes the array sort of like this:

```
class foo
{
private:
    CustomContainer<foo> m_listOfFoos;

public:
    foo  CreateFoo();            // Makes a foo, adds it to the list.
    foo  GetFoo( int i );        // Returns a foo
    int  GetListSize( );         // Returns the number of foos in the list
    void RemoveFoo( int i );     // Removes a foo
    void SortList();             // Sorts the list of foos in a custom way
};
```

The company uses a custom container written in 2002 and the `foo` is actually a pointer to a complicated class, but otherwise this is very close to the real situation.  I've already started working out the changeover from this container to an `std::vector`.

What I'm wondering is what is the best modern C++ practice for providing member functions to interact with the container.

Should I update the member functions we already have?  Or is there some modern C++ magic that allows me to give access to the container to another class so they can add, remove, and iterate with the vector in a better way?

Is there maybe a way to make the `std::vector` public but only allow read access?  Or a way to return an iterator class that does this?

Comment: One option is to just add a function that returns a (const) reference to `m_listOfFoos`.  Though that is often considered a code smell because it exposes your implementation.

Comment: `std::vector` has existed since C++98. Using it is not really anything to do with old vs modern C++..

Comment: You might expose a [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span). but no need to change interface when you change internal.

Comment: Re: " I've already started working out the changeover from this container to an std::vector." Why? What is the goal here? In general, if it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: Converting to a std::vector because the container relies on a library that is not cross-platform.  It's more work to fix that problem than to swap out the container.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a reason to change the interface (and valid reasons do exist), I wouldn't touch it.

Those valid reasons might include greater familiarity of maintainers, who will have used `vector`s before but not your custom interface. You could expose your vector by `const` reference in a `const` context to prevent modifications.

Mind you, a clear interface like that is not exactly hard to pick up and, this way, you can stick a mutex lock around accesses if you want to. Indeed, the strength of a good interface is that you can swap out its backing data store without exposing that change to any consumers.

In other words, there's really no generic answer to your question, but so far I do not see a reason to change your interface. Certainly, at least in my opinion, the "idiomatic" ways to expose a vector (and/or the reasons *not* to) haven't changed in recent years.

Comment: This class and the classes that use this class are all being rewritten for good reasons.  I do not have to change the interface, but it's still educational for me to know the right way to design this interface.

Comment: @Jimbo Again it's hard to speak in generalities here, but if this interface was the "right way" for you before, it's still the "right way" now, irrespective of the container behind it. The date on the calendar doesn't change that. Now, "for you" is the operative phrase because there is no "right way" for any of this. :)

Comment: Well keep in mind the scope of the question.  I'm not saying I *have to* change it or that I *want to* change it.  I am asking if there is a more modern way to handle access to a std::vector than I would know about speaking as a developer who has worked with C++ for 30 years, but only a very limited subset of what the language has become.  All that said, your answer is helpful.

Comment: @Jimbo And I've said a few times now that there isn't. Sorry, I'm not sure how else to put it. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a case of misused encapsulation. If outside classes need access directly to your private data member, the member should not be private in the first place. Anyways I would not recommend changing the interface of an existing class, instead the adapter pattern can come in handy if you want to adapt the interface of an existing class to match your new use case.

Comment: The contents of the container have to be protected.  If an outside class added, deleted, or removed items from the container it would cause bugs.